# DC, Crossfilter dependent Dropdown

Tags: arrays, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc and crossfilter.  I have made two dropdowns one for region and one for country.  My data are stored in CSV format one with column region and other with column Country.
Region contains for example : EMEA, ASPAC,NA
Country contains for example : Germany, Russia, US, India, Pakistan , China
It is one to many relation between region and country.
I am trying to dynamically populates value in Country dropdown when corresponding region is selected and do filtering accordingly.
I am unable to decide what should be my dimension and group.
Please help me out as I am very new to crossfilter and dc.  I can hardcode and do it with the help of javascript but I am not looking for that.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

I am using below code to populate and change the values in dropdown and apply crossfilter

```js
for (var i=0 ; i<regionDimGroup.size(); i++){
    if(region[i].key != ""){
   arrListRegion.push(region[i].key);
   document.getElementById("Region").options[i]=new Option(region[i].key);
    }
   }


d3.select('#Region').on('change', function(){
 var reg = Region.options[Region.options.selectedIndex].value
 if(reg == "All"){
  regionDim.filter(null)
 }else{
   regionDim.filter(reg)
 } 
      dc.redrawAll(); 
})
```

I have done something very similar for country